# Combining user input with a string literal in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, sockets, pointers

I'm trying to combine a string literal with input from the user and store it in an array as one message. I then have to send that message to a server. I'm fairly new and still a little confused about pointers.
this is what I've tried so far:

```
char input[1000];
char filename[100];
char message[2000];
printf("Please enter the name of a file \n");
scanf("%s", filename);
printf("what would you like to write to the file ?\n");
scanf("%s",input);
message = ("Write to file %s the following input: \n", filename, input);
if (send(csocket , message , strlen(message), 0) < 0)
{
  printf("send failed \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [`snprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html), given the nature of `"Write to file %s …"` (in other circumstances, you might use [`strcpy()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html) and
[`strcat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcat.html) — at least, those are the simplest tools, even if not completely safe). C has no built-in string operations; you have to use functions to work with strings.

```c
char input[1000];
char filename[100];
char message[2000];

printf("Please enter the name of a file \n");
if (scanf("%s", filename) != 1)
    …process error…
printf("what would you like to write to the file ?\n");
if (scanf("%s", input) != 10
    …process error…
snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "Write to file %s the following input: %s\n",
         filename, input);
if (send(csocket, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "send failed\n");
}
```

Beware: `scanf("%s", …)` only reads one 'word' — it skips leading whitespace characters (blanks, tabs, newlines) and then reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters up to the next whitespace character.  And you've not constrained the length of the input; you should!  (That would be `scanf("%99s", filename)` and `scanf("%999s", input)` — the off-by-one on lengths is sad but ancient history and therefore practically immutable.)

Comment: Thank you this completely solved my problem, I really appreciate the notes you left as well